# Rock-Paper-Scissors game for learning purposes

Tags: python, beginner, rock-paper-scissors

I just want your opinions about my code. How could I improve it? Is there a better method to do it?

```
from sys import exit
from random import randint

print "Welcome to the PIN Game 1!"
print "Tell me your name"

user = raw_input('> ')

#asks the user for an entry and prints what he has chosen
def start(): 
    print "%s, choose one of the options: " % user

    print """
    1. Rock
    2. Paper
    3. Scissors
    """

    choice = 0
    cpu_choice = randint(1,3)

    while choice <= 0 or choice >= 4:

        choice = int(raw_input('> '))
        if choice == 1:
            print "You chose ROCK!"
        elif choice == 2:
            print "You chose PAPER"
        elif choice == 3:
            print "You chose SCISSORS"
        else:
            print "What is your problem? Try again, this time choose a number between 1 and 3!"
    cpu_decision(cpu_choice)
    result(choice, cpu_choice)

#random cpu input
def cpu_decision(cpu):
    if cpu == 1:
        print "Your opponent chose ROCK!"
    elif cpu == 2:
        print "Your opponent chose PAPER!"
    else:
        print "Your opponent chose SCISSORS"

#if user loses
def lose():
    print "Sorry, you lost the match"

#if user wins
def win():
    print "Congratulations! You beat your opponent!!"

#prints the result
def result(user, comp):
    if user == comp:
        print "Gee! You tied!"
    elif user == 1 and comp == 2:
        lose()
    elif user == 1 and comp == 3:
        win()
    elif user == 2 and comp == 1:
        win()
    elif user == 2 and comp == 3:
        lose()
    elif user == 3 and comp == 1:
        lose()
    elif user == 3 and comp == 2:
        win()

    again()

#ask if the user wants to play again
def again():
    print """
    Wanna play again?
    1 for YES
    Anything else to quit
    """

    again1 = int(raw_input('> '))

    if again1 == 1:
        start()
    else:
        exit()

start()
```

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

#### Choice representation

You're using numbers to represent choices (rock/paper/scissors). That's a reasonable choice, but as it stands, you have the mapping between choices and numbers smeared all across your program. So you have to know when reading it that 1=rock, 2=scissors---no, wait, 2=paper---you can see how easy it is to make a mistake.

If you start off your program with something along the lines of:

```
ROCK = 1
PAPER = 2
SCISSORS = 3
```

then you can write code like:

```
if user == ROCK and comp == PAPER:
   # user loses
```

which is much easier to read.

The all-uppercase names are used by convention to indicate constants; python doesn't treat them differently.

Also note that this isn't really the *best* way to do this; what I'm describing is a clumsy way of doing an [enumerated type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type); there are [cleaner approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python) in all versions of Python, and [proper support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) for enums in Python 3. I'm suggesting a lightweight approach to suit where I've guessed your skill level to be.

#### Choice output

At the moment, you have lots of conditionals of the approximate form:

```
if choice == 1:
    print "Chose ROCK!"
elif choice == 2:
   print "Chose PAPER!"
```

You could define this mapping once at the top of your program:

```
names = { 1: "ROCK", 2: "PAPER", 3: "SCISSORS" }
```

and then refer to it later:

```
print "Chose {}!".format(names[choice])
```

Note that it would make sense to replace those literal numbers with the enumerated constants above; I'm just showing the literal numbers to avoid excessive coupling within this answer.

#### Data-driven victory conditions

You have a huge chunk of code:

```
if user == comp:
    # tie
elif user == 1 && comp == 2:
    lose()
elif user == 1 && comp == 3:
    win()
#...etc.
```

Even if we write it using named constants for the choices, it's still unwieldy, and the interaction between the conditional branches makes it easy to write bugs.

It would be easier to read and understand if you described those relationships in data:

```
outcomes = {
    ROCK: {PAPER: lose, SCISSORS: win},
    PAPER: {ROCK: win, SCISSORS: lose},
    SCISSORS: {ROCK: lose, PAPER: win}
}
```

and then just looked them up:

```
if user == comp:
    # tie
else:
   outcomes[user][comp]()
```

In that example, you have to declare `outcomes` after `win()` and `lose()`, as you're storing references to those functions in the dictionary; you could also choose some other way of representing the outcome (strings, a boolean, etc), although then you'd have to interpret it rather than just calling the function returned from the lookup.

Obviously, that `outcomes` data structure is rather redundant, as it encodes the rules both ways round: for a problem this size, that's probably simplest; if you had a larger, more complex game, I would suggest something like a relation:

```
beats = {(ROCK, SCISSORS), (PAPER, ROCK), (SCISSORS, PAPER)}
```

and then compute the [symmetric closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_closure) of that. But don't worry too much about that in your context.

Comment: That was a very complete answer. Thank you. I have updated my code and I used your insights

Comment: The obvious choice for clearly limited named options of a particular type is an enum and not 3 theoretically independent constants, apart from that good answer.

Comment: @Voo I agree in general---I was trying to pitch it at a very simple level to suit the OP (particularly given that they're using a "roll-your-own-enums" version of Python).

Comment: Fair point, installing third party libraries ( the backport of the official enum module to 2.x) is a bit much. I just forgot about the non existence since it's part of my template for any new project.

Comment: This answer (particularly the data driven victory conditions part) has the added benefit that your code does not get significantly longer when you start to implement Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock.

Answer (score 7):

You'd do well to use an enum or constants for your rock, paper and scissors.

For instance, what you've got here...

```
elif user == 1 and comp == 2:
    lose()
elif user == 1 and comp == 3:
    win()
elif user == 2 and comp == 1:
    win()
elif user == 2 and comp == 3:
    lose()
elif user == 3 and comp == 1:
    lose()
elif user == 3 and comp == 2:
    win()
```

That's not readable at all!

If you defined constants instead, you could do like this:

```
#near the top
rock = 1
paper = 2
scissors = 3

#in result
elif user == rock and comp == paper:
    lose()
elif user == rock and comp == scissors:
    win()
elif user == paper and comp == rock:
    win()
elif user == paper and comp == scissors:
    lose()
elif user == scissors and comp == rock:
    lose()
elif user == scissors and comp == paper:
    win()
```

And it becomes easier to spot if you made a mistake (like if you accidentally swapped the win condition for scissors vs paper with scissors vs rock).

If you want to learn more about that, I suggest googling about "enums" or "magic numbers". Additionally, we might want to use the style convention that constants are UPPER_SNAKE_CASE:

```
#near the top
ROCK = 1
PAPER = 2
SCISSORS = 3

#in result
elif user == ROCK and comp == PAPER:
    lose()
elif user == ROCK and comp == SCISSORS:
    win()
elif user == PAPER and comp == ROCK:
    win()
elif user == PAPER and comp == SCISSORS:
    lose()
elif user == SCISSORS and comp == ROCK:
    lose()
elif user == SCISSORS and comp == PAPER:
    win()
```

By using a specialized style for constants, it's easier to see that it's a constant, and not some local variable.

Comment: I updated the code with that ;)

Answer (score 5):

It's good that you're trying to use functions, but I think you're overusing them a bit.

```
#if user loses
def lose():
    print "Sorry, you lost the match"

#if user wins
def win():
    print "Congratulations! You beat your opponent!!"
```

Unless you intend to add more code to these (like perhaps a score keeping function) they're pretty redundant lines. You've just abstracted away a simple print call, but it might look like something more to someone else, so you're just creating confusion.

You have a function for `cpu_decision`, which is worthwhile, but you call `randint` outside the function, why not just call it from inside?

```
#random cpu input
def cpu_decision():
    choice = randint(1,3)
    if choice == 1:
        print "Your opponent chose ROCK!"
    elif choice == 2:
        print "Your opponent chose PAPER!"
    else:
        print "Your opponent chose SCISSORS"
    return choice
```

By using `return choice` you can get what number was chosen in the function instead of having to call `randint` elsewhere and pass the value into `cpu_decision`.

I also think that you should have the user input in its own function, similar to `cpu_decision` above, it can handle the printing and return the user's choice. Thaat way your `start` code can be much neater:

```
def start():
    print "%s, choose one of the options: " % user

    print """
    1. Rock
    2. Paper
    3. Scissors
    """
    choice = user_decision()
    cpu_choice = cpu_decision()
    result(choice, cpu_choice)
```

Your result code is confusing. It would be better if you grouped conditions instead.

```
#prints the result
def result(user, comp):
    if user == comp:
        print "Gee! You tied!"
    elif ((user == 1 and comp == 2) or (user == 2 and comp == 3)
          or (user == 3 and comp == 1)):
        lose()
    elif ((user == 1 and comp == 3) or (user == 2 and comp == 1)
          or (user == 3 and comp == 2)):
        win()
```

This is still confusing, just because there's a lot of condition checking of arbitrary numbers, but Pimgd's suggestion about enums would help that a lot.

You call `again` from `result`. Then `again` calls `start` which calls `result` which calls `again` which calls `start` which calls `result` which calls `again` which calls `start` which calls `result` which calls `again` which calls `start` which calls `result` which calls `again` which calls `start`...

You see where this is going? You've made a recursive pattern. After a certain number of calls Python will error out because of being too deep. That would be after a LOT of games, but it's still better practice to avoid it. You could instead set up an infinite game loop:

```
def main():
    while True:
        start()
        print """
        Wanna play again?
        1 for YES
        Anything else to quit
        """

        again1 = int(raw_input('> '))

        if again1 != 1:
            break
```

Now instead you can call `main`, which will loop forever until the user enters anything other than 1 after their game.

Comment: Ì think that `while 0 >= choice >= 4:` will alway give `False`

Comment: @oliverpool Derp, you're right, it's an `or` condition, and I turned it into an `and` without thinking it through. Thanks for correcting me!

Comment: You can still change that condition to `while not (0 < choice < 4)`.

Comment: I've turned the functions into variables using a dictionary, that way I could shrink a lot the result function. What do you think of it? The updated code is in the OP.

Comment: @mschlindwein A dictionary is also a good solution! I didn't suggest it but it definitely neatens code without needing full function definitions.

Answer (score 5):

Will I win maddest solution prize?

```
if user == comp:
    draw()
elif (user+2 ) % 3 == (comp + 3 ) % 3:
    win()
else:
    lose()
```

*EDIT*

```
[win, draw, lose][ (comp + 3 ) % 3 - (user+2 ) % 3] ()
```

Comment: Terrible for readability, but +1 anyway because modulo's the first thing I thought of when I saw this, too. =P

Comment: feel free to come check out PPCG any time ;)

Comment: -1 for being worse than OP. The problem with terse python/perl/haskell crap is their WTF/LOC is very high, for having fewer lines for more WTFs.

Comment: But hey, if we continue to increase wtf density, can we eventually create a wtf black hole?

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to fight back overengineering, which produces all kind of superflexible megametaconfigurable helloworlds. You see, just the opposite side of spectrum.

Comment: This isn't "maddest", not by a long shot. In fact, I would argue that this is the only "non-mad" way of solving this, because rock-paper-scissors  is in fact a mathematical relationship. See:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors#Additional_weapons

Answer (score 2):

A further suggestion to @Pimgd's answer:

You could also use 3 constants for WIN, TIE, LOSE and a function `user_result(user, comp)` which returns the result of the left argument. In this function you test for equality and return `TIE` if it's the case, otherwise you compare the choices

```
def user_result(user, comp):
    if user == comp:
        return TIE
    elif user == ROCK:
        return WIN if comp == SCISSORS else LOSE
    elif user == PAPER:
        return WIN if comp == ROCK else LOSE
    elif user == SCISSORS:
        return WIN if comp == PAPER else LOSE
```

Comment: I used that in combination with a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my code according to your answers:

- I created variables for the answers, and dictionaries to reference to them as suggested. Symmetric closure is a thing that I'll take a look at.
- I created a `user_decision` function and changed the again for the main function. I changed the result function, and now I am using variables and a dictionary to return win and lose (now they are variables, instead of functions).
- I created variables for the results.

```
from sys import exit
from random import randint

print "Welcome to the PIN Game 1!"
print "Tell me your name"

user = raw_input('> ')
print "%s, choose one of the options: " % user

#Constants
ROCK = 1
PAPER = 2
SCISSORS = 3

names = {ROCK: "ROCK", PAPER: "PAPER", SCISSORS: "SCISSORS"}

#asks the user for an entry and prints what he has chosen
def start(): 
   print """
   1. ROCK
   2. PAPER
   3. SCISSORS
   """

   choice = user_decision()
   cpu_choice = cpu_decision()
   result(choice, cpu_choice)
#user input
def user_decision():
    choice = 0

    while choice <= 0 or choice >=4:

        choice = int(raw_input('> '))
        if choice >= 1 or choice <= 3:
            print "You chose %s" % names[choice]
        else:
            print "What is your problem? Try again, this time choose a number between 1 and 3!"
    return choice

#random cpu input
def cpu_decision():
    choice = randint(1,3)
    print "Your opponent chose %s!" % names[choice]
    return choice

lose = "Sorry, you lost the match..."
win = "Congratulations, you won!!"

outcomes = {
    ROCK: {PAPER: lose, SCISSORS: win},
    PAPER: {ROCK: win, SCISSORS: lose},
    SCISSORS: {PAPER: win, ROCK: lose}
}

#prints the result
def result(user, comp):
    if user == comp:
        print "Gee! You tied"
    else:
        print outcomes[user][comp]

#ask if the user wants to play again
def main():
    while True:
        start()
        print """
    Wanna play again?
    1 for YES
    Anything else to quit
        """

        again1 = int(raw_input('> '))

        if again1 != 1:
            break

main()
```